# Subtract next row's datetime with current row's datetime based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

It might sound complex - I think it is.

I have an output like this:

```
| EmployeeID|      DateAndTime        | Type | AbsenceID |      DateEntered        |     LastModifiedDate    | minutes | DN |
|   ZB01    | 2014-09-22 08:01:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 | 2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 |   443   | 30 |
|   ZB01    | 2014-09-22 16:24:01.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 | 2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 |   443   | 30 |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 08:08:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 | 2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 |   397   | 31 |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 14:11:01.000 |  5   |    11     | 2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 | 2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 |   397   | 31 |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 15:15:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 |   397   | 31 |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 15:15:02.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-05-20 08:17:02.740 | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.883 |   397   | 31 |
|   TS44    | 2014-15-05 08:00:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 | 2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 |   450   | 32 |
|   TS44    | 2014-15-05 16:30:01.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 | 2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 |   450   | 32 |
```

Type 1 stands for an in-booking
Type 2 stands for an out-booking
Type 4 stands for an business absence in-booking.
Type 5 stands for an business absence out-booking.
Type 38 stands for absences (full-day).

When you make an type 4 or 5 booking you can select which absence is the reason. You see the reason at AbsenceId column. In the above example this stands for "dentist".

I want to get the total hours of absence from when the business absence begin to the next in- or out-booking is made. In the above example there's made an out-booking afterwards.

But what I wanted the output to be:

```
| EmployeeID|      DateAndTime        | Type | AbsenceID |      DateEntered        |     LastModifiedDate    | minutes | DN |absMinutes|
|   ZB01    | 2014-09-22 08:01:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 | 2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 |   443   | 30 |   0      |
|   ZB01    | 2014-09-22 16:24:01.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 | 2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 |   443   | 30 |   0      |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 08:08:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 | 2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 |   397   | 31 |   0      |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 14:11:01.000 |  5   |    11     | 2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 | 2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 |   397   | 31 |   64     |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 15:15:01.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 |   397   | 31 |   0      |
|   MR89    | 2014-05-19 15:15:02.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-05-20 08:17:02.740 | 2014-05-23 13:30:55.883 |   397   | 31 |   0      |
|   TS44    | 2014-15-05 08:00:01.000 |  1   |    0      | 2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 | 2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 |   450   | 32 |   0      |
|   TS44    | 2014-15-05 16:30:01.000 |  2   |    0      | 2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 | 2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 |   450   | 32 |   0      |
```

You see I have to kinds of minutes ind my example.
"Minutes" is the total hours of presence. The type 4 and 5 is calculated within the minutes.
"AbsMinutes" should be the time the employee have been absent. I thought of (pseudo code):

case when art = 5 and next-row = 1 or 2 then next-row's DateAndTime minus current row's DateAndTime.

My code:

```
select
    EmployeeID, DateAndTime, Type, AbsenceID, DateEntered, LastModified, Minutes, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by AUSWIDT order by convert(varchar(10),DATUMZEIT,20)) dn
from(--c
    select
        EmployeeID, DateAndTime, Type, AbsenceID, DateEntered, LastModified, Minutes, BookingKontrol,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by AUSWIDT, DATUMZEIT order by LETZT_AEND desc, dagsKontrol) rn
    from(--b
        select
            EmployeeID, DateAndTime, Type, AbsenceID, DateEntered, LastModified, Minutes
            ,case when Type = 38 then 1 when Type = 4 then 1 when Type = 5 then 1 when Type = 1 then 1 when Type = 2 then 1 else 2 end BookingKontrol
        from(--a
            select 
                t.EmployeeId EmployeeID, t.DateAndTime DateAndTime, t.type Type ,t.AbsenceId AbsenceID, t.DateEntered DateEntered, t.LastModified LastModified, h.minutes Minutes
            from
                Transaktion t, HistoricTime h
            where
                h.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId and
                convert(varchar(10),h.HistoricDate,20) = CONVERT(varchar(10),t.DateandTime,20)
        )a
    )b
    where BookingKontrol = 1
)c
where rn = 1

order by t.EmployeeId, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.DateandTime,20), t.LastModified LastModified
```

**Update**
I use a system where a newbie programmer can select tables and fields from a list, link them together and make conditions. When executed, the system will automatically write SELECT in front of all the selected choices so it becomes a select-statement. That means I can't start with a WITH-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cteSample
AS
( SELECT 'ZB01' AS EmployeeID,'2014-09-22 08:01:01.000' AS DateAndTime, 1 AS [Type],0 AS AbsenceID
    ,'2014-09-22 08:01:21.245' AS DateEntered,'2014-09-22 08:01:21.245' AS LastModifiedDate , 443 AS [MINUTES] ,30 AS DN
UNION ALL SELECT 'ZB01','2014-09-22 16:24:01.000',2,0,'2014-09-22 16:24:37.522','2014-09-22 16:24:37.522',443,30
UNION ALL SELECT 'MR89','2014-05-19 08:08:01.000',1,0,'2014-05-19 08:08:34.680','2014-05-19 08:08:34.680',397,31
UNION ALL SELECT 'MR89','2014-05-19 14:11:01.000',5,11,'2014-05-19 14:11:04.510','2014-05-19 14:11:04.510',397,31
UNION ALL SELECT 'MR89','2014-05-19 15:15:01.000',1,0,'2014-05-23 13:30:55.837','2014-05-23 13:30:55.837',397,31
UNION ALL SELECT 'MR89','2014-05-19 15:15:02.000',2,0,'2014-05-20 08:17:02.740','2014-05-23 13:30:55.883',397,31
UNION ALL SELECT 'TS44','2014-15-05 08:00:01.000',1,0,'2014-15-05 08:00:02.822','2014-15-05 08:00:02.822',450,32
UNION ALL SELECT 'TS44','2014-15-05 16:30:01.000',2,0,'2014-15-05 16:30:45.675','2014-15-05 16:30:45.675',450,32)


SELECT
A.*
,CASE
WHEN AbsenceID <> 0 AND B.[Type] IN(1,2) THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DateEntered,B.DateAndTime) 
ELSE 0 END AS absMinutes
FROM
cteSample AS A 
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        B.[Type]
        ,B.DateAndTime
    FROM cteSample AS B
    WHERE
        A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
        AND A.DateAndTime < B.DateAndTime
        --AND B.[Type] >= 1 
        --AND B.[Type] <= 2
    ORDER BY 
        B.DateAndTime ASC
)B
```

and the output:

```
EmployeeID DateAndTime             Type        AbsenceID   DateEntered             LastModifiedDate        MINUTES     DN          absMinutes
 ZB01       2014-09-22 08:01:01.000 1           0           2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 2014-09-22 08:01:21.245 443         30          0
 ZB01       2014-09-22 16:24:01.000 2           0           2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 2014-09-22 16:24:37.522 443         30          0
 MR89       2014-05-19 08:08:01.000 1           0           2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 2014-05-19 08:08:34.680 397         31          0
 MR89       2014-05-19 14:11:01.000 5           11          2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 2014-05-19 14:11:04.510 397         31          64
 MR89       2014-05-19 15:15:01.000 1           0           2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 2014-05-23 13:30:55.837 397         31          0
 MR89       2014-05-19 15:15:02.000 2           0           2014-05-20 08:17:02.740 2014-05-23 13:30:55.883 397         31          0
 TS44       2014-15-05 08:00:01.000 1           0           2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 2014-15-05 08:00:02.822 450         32          0
 TS44       2014-15-05 16:30:01.000 2           0           2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 2014-15-05 16:30:45.675 450         32          0
```

Comment: That looks great, but.. I forgot to mention that I can't use WITH in my system where I create the queries.. I tried to use your example where i replaced the WITH-query with the already existiing select-query I showed, but it's not working

Comment: WITH is just the source of my data. You can use temp table  or variable table

Comment: I tried to test your code by changing some of the Types to 4 or 5 and AbsenceID to anything else than 0. I expected to get some absMinutes greater than zero but nothing happened. I'm kind of noob when it comes to SQL and I don't understand some of the code by 100%. How should I understand this line: WHEN AbsenceID <> 0 AND B.[Type] IN(1,2) THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DateEntered,B.DateAndTime) ? it is the "B.TYPE IN(1,2)" I don't get

Comment: next row should have type  1 or 2